# MongooseSeverSelection Error while deploying backend on Render

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LouX5.jpg)

The error says that your IP address may not be whitelisted but I whitelisted my IP address on mongodb cluster,also backend works fine on pc but throws error while deploying. Please anyone help me with this .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not upload images of code or error messages! -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors Did you read the error message?

Comment: Which IP you have whitelisted? Your personal PC's or the web service IP that is running at `Render`?

Comment: whitelist `0.0.0.0` in your cluster

Comment: Pratheesh I searched for ip config on cmd and it showed my ip address that i whitelisted on mongodb

Comment: @buga thanks man it's working now but how will you please explain me why we have to do this?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` whitelists all ip addresses. your ip was probably not whitelisted which is why it wasn't working.